# Error -36 "some data can't be read or written" when copying files from SD card

Tags: finder, file-transfer, sd-card

I want to copy files from my SD card to my Desktop but for some of the files I get:

> The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “GOPR0054.MP4” can’t be read or written. (Error code -36)

I tried to use dot_clean because it seems to have done the trick for others:

```
dot_clean Path/To/Directory
```

Didn't work.

I have no idea what error -36 is or how it can be solved.
My SD card is in ExFAT format (if that matters).

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.2.

Comment: Error 36 is now and has, for a *long* time been an Apple file system error that boils down to "file is damaged" and/or "premature end of file" Its possible that a file recovery program or service could recover the file or its remains. Otherwise I would reformat the card and then do a whole lot of writing and reading to/from the card to make sure its not a bad card.

Comment: @SteveChambers is correct on all three counts: (1) Error -36 is an **input/output (I/O) error** and this often means the file wasn't _completed_ correctly for the particular file format, or that it's corrupted for some reason. (2) You're best bet is to use data recovery software (there are many) or a file extractor (such as [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/) to see what can be recovered. (3) Reformat the card and _really_ test it before using it for anything critical. There may be nothing wrong with it (the GoPro battery may have died while saving, etc), but you'd want to be sure.

Comment: Oh, and just to be clear, I have no affiliation with File Juicer whatsoever!

Comment: I had the same problem transferring from a flash drive to my iMac. I tried dot_clean as others have suggested. Still no real answer, but when I tried the same flash drive on my MacBook Pro, it worked fine. This leads me to believe the issue may be in the iMac itself.

Comment: I had issues dealing with this with the Mac so I used a Win 10 machine to transfer the files and it worked fine. Bad form, Apple.

Answer (score 3):

Not true; it's a privacy issue with the xfat format. You can copy the files via terminal: `mv` plus space, drag the file, plus drag the destiny. If that doesn't work, you'll have to change the format of the file.

Comment: How do I delete these files?

Comment: I tried both dot_clean and copying with the `mv` command. Every time I got OP's error.

Comment: What's "not true"?

Comment: `cp -r DIR DIR_TO` worked for me. however it was not an issue of copying between disks; i was trying to copy a folder from my desktop (icloud) into another documents folder (icloud).

Answer (score 1):

I had numerous files filmed in high quality and it would throw the same error and I wouldnt be able to copy it. I could see it in preview and in FCPX but I couldnt export or copy it. What I did was compress the file that was not working directly on the SD card and then copy the compressed file to the desktop. After it finally copied,I then uncompressed it in desktop and voila. I had the file saved on the desktop.

Comment: After you've saved your files that couldn't be copied, format the card to give it a clean start.